# Javascript onclick event takes two clicks

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to figure out how to make this one click event to take only one click, as it currently takes two. Before I had the on click event inline, but after reading here, I changed it to the code below but still did not work.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("divinput");
input.addEventListener("click", myFunction2);

function myFunction2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("recentsearch");
  var element = document.getElementById("searchbox");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    element.style.borderRadius = "24px 24px 0px 0px";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    element.style.borderRadius = "24px";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="divinput" class="divinput">
  <input type="text" class="textarea">
</div>
```

Comment: It may help to provide a [working demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue by including the HTML elements with IDs "recentsearch" and "searchbox" as well as any relevant CSS.